# Is there any way how I can get JSON raw data from Splunk for a given query?

Tags: getjson, restful-authentication, splunk

Is there any way how I can get JSON raw data from Splunk for a given query in a RESTful way?

Consider the following timechart query:

```
 index=* earliest=<from_time> latest=<to_time> | timechart  span=1s count
```

Key things in the query are: 1. Start/End Time, 2. Time Span (say sec) and 3. Value (say count)

The expected JSON response would be:

```
{"fields":["_time","count","_span"],
   "rows":[ ["2014-12-25T00:00:00.000-06:00","1460981","1"],
            ...,
            ["2014-12-25T01:00:00.000-06:00","536889","1"]
          ]
}
```

This is the XHR (ajax calls) for the output_mode=json_rows calls. This requires session and authentication setups.

I’m looking for a RESTful implementation of the same with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using the curl command

```
curl -k -u admin:changeme --data-urlencode search="search index=* earliest=<from_time> latest=<to_time> | timechart  span=1s count" -d "output_mode=json" https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export
```

Comment: Thanks Illusionist! I'm looking for a restful implementation so that I can consume the JSON data from my REST client implementation. I'm aware of this solution and will be using it at the worse scenario. Thanks again!

Comment: @TonyPuthenveettil, you need vote the answer for thanks, if it fixes your problem.